# How to get the window id with title of every process?

Tags: applescript

I'm using the following simple script:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the title of every window of every process
```

Which works by printing titles of every window.

```
tell application "System Events" to get the id of every window of every process
```

The above script prints `missing value`

```
{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {missing value, missing value}, {}, {missing value}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {missing value, missing value}, {missing value}, {}, {}, {missing value, missing value}, {missing value}, {missing value, missing value}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
```

How can I get the window id of every window?

Is it possible to get the window id and window title at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can get the window id and window title at the same time:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the {title, id} of every window of every process
```

However, many/most processes are invisible ones, so you'll want to reduce your list:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the {title, id} of every window of (every process whose visible is true)
```

And further, id is not something set in most windows. Perhaps you can say more about what you're trying to accomplish. You can examine the potential window properties with:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the properties of every window of (every process whose visible is true)
```

Comment: id value is missing. `{{missing value}, {missing value, missing value}, {missing value, missing value, missing value, missing value}, {missing value}, {missing value, missing value}, {missing value}, {missing value}, {missing value}}`

Comment: Yes, I already told you. "id" is not a property set for windows in the UI typically. There is not id property. If you say more about what you're trying to accomplish, then maybe we could help further.

Comment: I don't know about OP, but I just need a consistent way to identify and differentiate between all (visible) windows. I'm writing an applescript to track and rearrange windows, and there are 2 issues: 1. window names/titles change (e.g. Safari) and 2.  some windows have the same name (e.g. Terminal). If you know how to consistently and uniquely refer to a window, I could use a tip. Otherwise, I'm just going to have to skip windows I can't uniquely identify.

Comment: I should also point out that the identification method needs to survive a reboot...